# is there any way to import all tables not views from RDBMS to hive using sqoop

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop2

I m trying to import  800 tables  from SQL server to hive using sqoop import-all command, i have some views and some tables in SQL database i want to import only tables not views in hive using sqoop

also when i m doing it with import all command if there is any error sqoop exits at that point again have to start the process from the beginning. 
errors are like naming conventions datatype issue, no primary key in SQL table.
thank you